# Supersede input:text change handler based on button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want a text-input change event to disable edits to other (rather complex)fields in a form until the ok-button has been clicked. I want the user to be able to click the ok-button while still having the text-input focused without having the input-text change handler run. The problem is that this leaves the text-input field and triggers the change event before the ok-button click event.

```
jQ('#text-input').change(function(){
    //disable other inputs until ok-button is clicked
}

jQ('#ok-button').click(function(){
    //save changes and re-enable other inputs
}
```

The events are fired at practically the same time when clicking the ok-button while the text-input is focused, but the change event is first. Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/piyushjain7/X6K3W/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this made me realize I wasn't explaining the problem correctly. I updated the question to reflect the real issue. To replicate the problem in your fiddle type anything in the first field and then without leaving that field click the okButton. It flashes for a moment, which is what I am trying to avoid. Thanks again!

Comment: Perfect. This kind of hit me over the head on the way out of the building. Yes this is a solution that works perfectly. I'm curious if there is a way to do it with some kind of catch next event fired type solution, but this solution is elegant and flows well. Thanks!